# How to return a list on the method OnResponse used on retrofit?

Tags: android, list, return, retrofit

I am trying to do like this ...

```
  public final List<ClientResponse> returnedList2 = new ArrayList<>();
  clientPost3(nome, returnedList2);
```

And then calling the method clientPost3 which is bellow:

```
 public void clientPost3(String nome, final List<ClientResponse> returnedList) {

    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .baseUrl(SERVER_URL)
            .build();

    final Interface service = retrofit.create(Interface.class);

    Call<List<ClientResponse>> call = service.postClient(nome);

    call.enqueue(new Callback<List<ClientResponse>>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<List<ClientResponse>> call, Response<List<ClientResponse>> response) {
            for(ClientResponse clientResponse: response.body()){
                Log.e(TAG, clientResponse.getCliente());
                returnedList.add(clientResponse);

            }
            Log.e(TAG, "Success");
            Log.e("Teste2", returnedList.toString());
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<List<ClientResponse>> call, Throwable t) {
            Log.e(TAG, "FAIL");
        }

    });

}
```

However, returnedList2 is empty is becoming empty after the call of the method clientPost3.

What should I do to obtain the list returnedList which is inside onResponse?

Comment: You have 2 options: 1- declare returnedList2 at class level, 2- use a callback or a method which takes the list and uses it

Comment: Retrofit is asynchronous! Any code immediately after clientPost3 is almost always going to execute before onResponse even happens... Returning the list isn't the problem. The problem is calling the methods in the correct order

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this,

```
    public void clientPost3(String nome, final List<ClientResponse> returnedList) {

        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .baseUrl(SERVER_URL)
                .build();

        final Interface service = retrofit.create(Interface.class);

        Call<List<ClientResponse>> call = service.postClient(nome);

        call.enqueue(new Callback<List<ClientResponse>>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<List<ClientResponse>> call, Response<List<ClientResponse>> response) {
                returnedList2.clear();
                returnedList2.addAll( response.body().getClientResponse());

            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<List<ClientResponse>> call, Throwable t) {
                Log.e(TAG, "FAIL");
            }

        });

    }
```

Comment: Why do you need to pass the list as a parameter?

Answer (score 1):

Or rxJava, something like this:

```
service.postClient(nome)
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
    .subscribe(response -> returnedList2.addAll(response.getClientResponse()),throwable -> Log.e(TAG, "FAIL"))
```

Comment: You assume the question compiled RxJava?

Comment: I assume it could be changed to rxjava

Answer (score 0):

You can use by this way

```
 public List<ClientResponse> returnedList2 = new ArrayList<>();

 public void clientPost3(String nome, final List<ClientResponse> returnedList) {

Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
        .baseUrl(SERVER_URL)
        .build();

final Interface service = retrofit.create(Interface.class);

Call<List<ClientResponse>> call = service.postClient(nome);

call.enqueue(new Callback<List<ClientResponse>>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(Call<List<ClientResponse>> call, Response<List<ClientResponse>> response) {
        returnedList2 = response.body();
        Log.e(TAG, "Success");
        Log.e("Teste2", returnedList.toString());
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(Call<List<ClientResponse>> call, Throwable t) {
        Log.e(TAG, "FAIL");
    }

});

}
```

Comment: Don't use `=` in the response. Clear + addAll are more correct

Answer (score 0):

Your ClientResponse fields have to be named as in response from server or be marked @SerializedName("")

For example your response from server is in Json:

```
{
 "time": "15:29",
 "date": "11.08.2017"
}
```

Then your class have to be like this

```
class MyClass{
private String time;
private String date;
//getters, setters, stc
}
```

or

```
class MyClass{
@SerializedName("time")
private String cerrentTime;
@SerializedName("date")
private String currentDate;
//getters, setters, etc
```

then your response will be parsed properly.

Other problem may be that you check your list2 after call.enqueue, but Retrofit works asynchronous and better way to use it is with some callback interface like:

```
interface MyInterface{
 void onSuccess(ArrayList<ClientResponse> list);
}
```

implement this interface in your activity, or fragment or where you need. Then pass MyInterface reference to your class where you make call and in your onResponse method just use `myInterfaceInstanse.onSuccess(response.body());` and continue your work with this response in onSuccess realization.

Sorry, for such a confused answer, hope you understand me :)